# Android : Calling Activity from Fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-audiomanager, android-mediarecorder

I am using fragments inside an activity. I am using MediaRecorder to for audio recording.
I have two part of an activity. 
1st itself the Activity which will list the recorded file. 
On it's right side the AudioRecording Activity is called when one select to record for a new file.
When the any of the listed file is selected i am using AudioPlayer as to play the recorded file.
I am here able to convert the Activity into fragment but when i press on Stop it is terminating the application.

Please anyone can answer. My audiorecorder is working fine when i use it as simple activity.
Any solution like if i can call that activity in that fragment or something like that.?
Please help me if anyone knows.

Comment: to call another activity from fragment use likethis:

Answer (score 35):

Get the parent activity using get activity then do as usual.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getapplicationcontext(), BookmarkActivity.class);
getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is another alternative method. This worked for me.

```
public class **YourFragmentClass** extends Fragment {

    Context context; //Declare the variable context

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Pass your layout xml to the inflater and assign it to rootView.
      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.**yourfragmentxml**, container, false); 
            context = rootView.getContext(); // Assign your rootView to context

            Button **yourButton** = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.**your_button_id**);
            **yourButton**.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Pass the context and the Activity class you need to open from the Fragment Class, to the Intent
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, **YourActivityClass**.class); 
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly what I was searching for...;)

Answer (score 3):

To call another `activity` from `fragment` use this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can simply call**

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),TheNextActivity.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

**In Fragment Class**

```
 getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(gwtActivity(),MainActivity.class));
 getActivity().finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fragment should have a parent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way of calling Activity from Fragment class is that make interface in Fragment and add `onItemClick()` method in that interface. Now implement it to your first activity and call second activity from there.