# Call activity from fragment in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have two classes:

One is `Fragment1` which containts fragment - like this:

```
public class Tab extends FragmentActivity
```

the second one is `activity` - like this:

```
public class Wallpaper extends Activity
```

Now I want to start Activity from `Fragment1` how can I do this ?

Comment: To call activity from fragment, checkout http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity . However, your class Tab seems to be not a Fragment, but activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Wallpaper.class);

// intent.putExtra(....); // put your data

startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3):

> I want to start Activity from Fragment1 how can I do this ?

You have this

`public class Tab extends FragmentActivity` in which case you can use the below unless you are starting activity from fragment class

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Tab.this,Wallpaper.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Use the below in your fragment

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Wallpaper.class);
  getActivtiy().startActivity(intent);
```

`getActivity`

Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

There is an example in the docs check the same

Comment: well when i m using this line "Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity.class); startActivity(i);" i am getting error at getActivity()..like create methid for getActivity();

Comment: @user2783386 that is bcoz your using it in `Tab` class in which case use  `Intent intent = new Intent(Tab.this,Wallpaper.class);
 startActivity(intent)` and `Tab` class does not extend `Fragment`. `FragmentActivtiy` is Base class for activities that want to use the support-based Fragment and Loader APIs.

Comment: @user2783386 i doubt whether you have a class that extends `Fragment`.

Comment: well forgot every thing i have frame-Layout and i want to show wallpaper class then how can i do ?

Comment: @user2783386 why do you need a frame-layout. use fragmentactivity to host a fragment which is in the support library.

Comment: well my porpose is when some one click on action bar then i have to show different activity and in action bar i have three  button that's why

Comment: @user2783386 you are getting it all wrong. You have tabs not buttons i assume and you need to navigate to show the content of a different xml on each tab selection. that is what you want right. and pls be clear with your next qiestion that you asked

Comment: @RahulGupta just bcoz i commented and flagged your question you unaccepted the answer that is not good. Certainly i am not going to answer your questions in the future. what a waste of time

Comment: y are you downvote at my question  ? thats why if u want to answer then give your answer

Comment: @RahulGupta i had commented first only after you commented i flagged and downvoted and if i know i will certainly answer. It was downvoted coz it was a duplicate of previous question asked

Comment: @RahulGupta and check this before coming to conclusions http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled.

Comment: Duplicate questions are not necessarily bad; different descriptions of the same problem help future visitors to find the answers they're looking for. However, asking a duplicate question may

Comment: @RahulGupta tell me if it not a duplicate i will remove the downvote but even i do others will still downvote and close the questions. but it certainly looks exact duplicate. but yours is exactly duplicate i see no change except for few words which are too minor. if you still have a problem bring it on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: fine bro if u have solution then provide here

Comment: @RahulGupta if i know i will certainly help you can delete the question and your downvotes will be reversed. and remember not to ask duplicate questions if you don't find answers

Comment: if you seen my question then hwy are you not answered there ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40174/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-rahul-gupta)

Answer (score 0):

See here: [Android : Calling Activity from Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637693/android-calling-activity-from-fragment) - the first result on Google searching for your question title...

Comment: well when i m using this line "Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity.class);
startActivity(i);"

Comment: @user2783386 do you have that  line in a class that extends `Fragment`?

Comment: well when i m using this line "Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity.class);
startActivity(i);" i am getting error at getActivity()..like create methid for getActivity();

Comment: @Raghunandan no in second class i dont extend fragment

Answer (score 0):

try this

Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), mFragmentFavorite.class);
startActivity(intent);