# How to call activity directly without clicking button?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on `stripe-terminal-android app`, they have built-in app, but I wanted to customise it according to use-case.

link of [stripe-app-repo](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-terminal-android)

when I open app it first gives me fragment, to `Discover Readers`, [link-of-code](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-terminal-android/blob/dcb8f4af62b75b51b00f6e30e2bae40e5852410a/Example/javaapp/src/main/java/com/stripe/example/javaapp/fragment/TerminalFragment.java#L71),

but I wanted that to automatically clicked and without any click it should work as it was clicked, so that no need to manually Discover-Readers, everytime.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NotNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    view.findViewById(R.id.discover_button).setOnClickListener(v -> {
    final FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
    if (activity instanceof NavigationListener) {
        ((NavigationListener) activity).onRequestDiscovery(viewModel.getSimulated());
    }
});
```

but, current code is to call `onRequestDiscovery`, is executed only after clicking-button, how can I do like we do in javascript?

`document.getElementById("demo").click())` or similar-one? so no need to manually-click and it would proceed further.

Edit after answer by Sebastein.

added this line, but I wanted to click and call function `onRequestDiscovery()` which is not working.

[image]
`view.findViewById(R.id.discover_button).performClick()`

screenshot added after edited-response by Sebastein,

[image]

Comment: found this link useful, but working/figuring it out, how to make it work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637693/android-calling-activity-from-fragment

Comment: so so sorry, to post-without reading error, I by-mistakenly wrote function `getSharedPreferencesgetSharedPreferences` twice, while I must have tried `getSharedPreferences()` once only. sorry community for that, but I won't delete this post to hide my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use method *performClick()* after adding the click listener :

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NotNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.discover_button)
    button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        final FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
        if (activity instanceof NavigationListener) {
            ((NavigationListener) activity).onRequestDiscovery(viewModel.getSimulated());
        }
    button.performClick();
});
```

but for me the best way is not to start the activity in the fragment but directly in the activity which instantiate the fragment.

Comment: thanks @Sebastien but it's now working, I am updating my answer to your reply.

Comment: i've said you to call performClick() AFTER setOnClickListener !

Comment: okay Sebastein, I tried that to adding after  `setOnClickListener` `view.findViewById(R.id.discover_button).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            final FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
            if (activity instanceof NavigationListener) {
                ((NavigationListener) activity).onRequestDiscovery(viewModel.getSimulated());
            }
        });

        view.findViewById(R.id.discover_button).performClick();
`

Comment: could you give whole snippet-reference please?

Comment: Hi Sebastein I already saw your newly-edited reply but it's too didn't work. I am updating my question  and posting screenshot of error-while-compiling. `getSharedPreferencesgetSharedPreferences`

Comment: thre's another error in your fragment code, find where are you using getSharedPreferencesgetSharedPreferences, the error comes from that

Comment: new error is thrown at getSharedPreferences,  https://github.com/stripe/stripe-terminal-android/blob/dcb8f4af62b75b51b00f6e30e2bae40e5852410a/Example/javaapp/src/main/java/com/stripe/example/javaapp/fragment/TerminalFragment.java#L44

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202056/discussion-between-sebastienrieu-and-ganeshdeshmukh).

Comment: hey @Sebastein, I have replied in chat.

Comment: it was my error after your first reply, sorry for pastingErrorWithoutReadingError.